# react_table__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2___default(...) is not a function

Tags: reactjs, webpack, react-table

I am creating a table in React using [react-table](https://react-table.tanstack.com/docs/quick-start) and following their quick start guide. But I am getting a type error.
[image]

This is the component that I have

```
import React from 'react';
import useTable from 'react-table';

function Entities(props) {
  const data = React.useMemo(
    () => [
      {
        col1: 'Hello',
        col2: 'World'
      },
      {
        col1: 'react-table',
        col2: 'rocks'
      },
      {
        col1: 'whatever',
        col2: 'you want'
      }
    ],
    []
  );

  const columns = React.useMemo(
    () => [
      {
        Header: 'Column 1',
        accessor: 'col1' // accessor is the "key" in the data
      },
      {
        Header: 'Column 2',
        accessor: 'col2'
      }
    ],
    []
  );

  const table = useTable({ columns, data });

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{props.heading}</h1>
      {table}
    </div>
  );
}
export default Entities;
```

Can someone guide me what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

The return statement of a React function is commonly a bit of javascript that will be rendered to screen. The result value of useTable is not something that can be rendered, so your use of {table} in the return statement of Entities is causing this exception.

Going from the example script available in the react-table github repository, you would be better defining the Table object in a separate function, something along the lines of:

```
function Table({ columns, data }) {
  // Use the state and functions returned from useTable to build your UI
  const {
    getTableProps,
    getTableBodyProps,
    headerGroups,
    rows,
    prepareRow,
  } = useTable({
    columns,
    data,
  })

  // Render the UI for your table
  return (
    <table {...getTableProps()}>
      <thead>
        {headerGroups.map(headerGroup => (
          <tr {...headerGroup.getHeaderGroupProps()}>
            {headerGroup.headers.map(column => (
              <th {...column.getHeaderProps()}>{column.render('Header')}</th>
            ))}
          </tr>
        ))}
      </thead>
      <tbody {...getTableBodyProps()}>
        {rows.map((row, i) => {
          prepareRow(row)
          return (
            <tr {...row.getRowProps()}>
              {row.cells.map(cell => {
                return <td {...cell.getCellProps()}>{cell.render('Cell')}</td>
              })}
            </tr>
          )
        })}
      </tbody>
    </table>
  )
}
```

and then using that object in the return statement of Entities: changing it to be something along the lines of

```
return (
    <div>
      <h1>{props.heading}</h1>
      <Table columns={columns} data={data}
    </div>
  );
```

You can drop the call to useTable in Entities, as that is now encapsulated in the Table function